# InfoPath Query String using SharePoint FormServer.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I am trying to push data into a form developed in InfoPath which is loaded from FormServices.aspx.

I know how to do this with the `QueryString` command from SharePoints Edit page but The form has to be loaded with the FormServer.aspx command in the browser. What I want to do is add `&Ref=12345` to the URL and for that to add `12345` to a field called Ref_Number in my form.

I can not use VB or C# to do this as SharePoint here is very strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to not be possible via the form services but I have been able to work around this by creating a page using the `QueryString` for my `&Ref=12345` but also added `&IsDlg=0` which removed the ribbon. This was the effect they wanted from form services so hohum jobs a gooden now.